# CMS for integrating high volume indexable tables

Tags: database, content-management-system

I wish to use a CMS with the following additional requirement:
- to create a table with 5000 items which are searchable by about 10 of the fields (its basically a product catalogue table.

Ideally I would want to use a CMS with a basic ecommerce capability and add a vertical partition in a 1:1 reference to the catalog table of the main CMS product table and change queries within the CMS package to reference / search the additional field information.

Which CMS would be the most appropriate for extending?  The CMS must have at least basic ecommerce capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

[eZ Publish with standard shop features](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Modules/shop/%28language%29/eng-GB)
plus [eZ Find](http://doc.ez.no/Extensions/eZ-Publish-extensions/eZ-Find).
Both are free OSS